# How can I an iframe's source and render elements conditionally in my existing application?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, iframe

I have a Laravel PHP application. Its url has always been site1.example.com.

I am developing a new site, and I want to temporarily show the content from the old site in an iframe on the new site (I know there are better alternatives for moving or transitioning the content, but I have to use an iframe due to other limitations).

I need to be able to strip the header and footer off of the old site and just show the plain unstyled content from the old site in the iframe.

A coworker tried the following in php in the old site's template to detect where the request is coming from and render only the parts of the template that are needed.

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'site1.example.com')
{
…
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work because the request is coming from site1.example.com regardless of whether its loaded directly from the browser or from an iframe.

How can I check if the site is being loaded through the iframe on site2.example.com and render conditionally accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Method 1:**

Use JavaScript `window.parent.location` inside the frame itself to get the `url` of parent window. Then `show()` or `hide()` elements relative to `url` using javascript.

- **Method 2:**

Open the `<iframe>` by adding a `querystring` variable to the `url`. As soon as you get the variable, save it as a session cookie and in every page check that session cookie to decide. E.g.

`<iframe src="mysite.com?q=iframe" />`

Comment: @KinsDotNet There is a verb missing in your title, and I cannot edit less than six _(I don't remember the exact number)_ characters, so I went forward and edited the content too, I was trying to be nice. Sorry...